# C-Struct vs Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, memory-management, struct

I am currently working on a Conway's Game of Life simulator for the iPhone and I had a few questions about memory management. Note that I am using ARC. 
For my application, I am going to need a large amount of either C style `structs` or Objective-C objects to represent cells. There may be a couple thousand of these, so obviously, memory management came to mind. 
**`Structs`** My argument for structs is that the cells do not need typical OO properties. The only thing that they will be holding is two `BOOL` values, so there will not be huge amount of memory chewed up by these cells. Also, I need to utilize a two-dimensional array. With structs, I can use the C-style 2d arrays. As far as I know, there is no replacement for this in Objective-C. I feel that it is overkill to create an object for just two boolean values. 
**Objective-C objects** My argument (and most other people's) is that the memory management around Objective-C objects is very easy and efficient with ARC. Also, I have seen arguments that a `struct` is not such a big memory reduction to an object.

So, my question. Should I go with the old-school, lean, and compatible with two-dimensional array `structs`? Or should I stick with the typical Objective-C objects and risk the extra memory used.

Afterthoughts: If you recommend Objective-C objects, provide an alternate storage method that represents a two-dimensional array. This is critical and is one of the biggest downsides of going with Objective-C objects.
Thankyou.

Comment: simply use bitfields of an integer you can wrap this with NSNumber to behave like an objective-c object. and a word of advice. Apple's guide lines is that you should stick with the highest level of abstraction and only if you encounter a performance problem optimise or go back to a lower level. Worrying too much about performance before trying out can sometimes be wasting alot of time in my honest experience.

Comment: @nsuinteger Then I lose two-dimensional arrays when I wrap in objc class. This is one of the advantages of using a primitive, 2d arrays.

Comment: +1 and hats off to you for asking the question and considering the trade-offs, regardless. My thoughts in answer below. -RP

Comment: For future reference `SomeObject *item = someArray[row][col];` is perfectly valid syntax in objective-C, provided that `row` and `col` are integer values, and `someArray` is an NSArray of rowArrays, where each rowArray is an NSArray of `SomeObject`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"... If you are trying to build a Game of Life server with 100,000 users playing concurrently, memory footprint might matter. For a single-person implementation on any modern device, even a mobile one, memory size is pretty academic.
Therefore, do whatever either gets the game up and running fastest or (better) makes the code most readable and maintainable. Human cycles cost more than computer cycles. Suppose you needed a third boolean for each cell of the game... wouldn't an object you could extend save a ton of time rather than hardcoded array indices? (A struct is a lot better than an array of primitives for this reason...)
I've certainly used denser representations of data when I need to, but the overhead in programmer time has to be worth it. Just my $.02...

Comment: Good point on the fact that single player memory won't be that big of a deal, even on a mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just 2 BOOL values that you are going to store for every cell, then you could just use an array of integers to do the job. For example:

Let us assume that the two bool values are boolX and boolY, we could combine them into an int as:

```
int combinedBool = boolY + (10*boolX);
```

So you can retrieve the two bool values like:

```
BOOL boolX, boolY;
boolX = combinedBool/10;
boolY = combinedBool%10;
```

And then you can store the whole board in the form a single dimension array of integers with the index of each cell represented by `((yIndex*width)+xIndex)` where `width` is the number of cells left-to-right on your board and, `xIndex` and `yIndex` represent the X and Y coordinates of the cell on your board.

Hope this helps with your memory management and cell organisation.

Comment: Thankyou for your thoughtful response and clever way to store booleans in one integer.

Comment: But if you really want to lose the representational power and get a small footprint, why would you waste up to 62 bits per pair of bools?  Why not just pack 32 pairs in a 64 bit uint?

Answer (score 0):

You could build one and test it's size with `malloc_size(myObject)`.  Thousands of pairs of bools will be small enough.  In fact, you'll be able to make the objects larger and enjoy the benefits of the OO design.  For example, what if the cells also kept pointers to their neighboring cells.  The cells could compute their own t+1 state with cached access to their neighbors.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. Also, is `malloc_size()` the same thing as `sizeof()`?

Comment: sizeof is more like the theoretical size, worked out at compile time.  malloc size will let you know what was actually allocated.